# Не раскрывается spinner

Tags: android

Мне нужно создать spinner программным путем, не компоновкой, мне это удается сделать и spinner раскрывается как и положено, но мне так же нужно указать атрибут style для него, как я понял это делается из конструктора.
Я указываю стиль, и потом spinner и вовсе перестает раскрываться...

Вот код создания spinner'a:

```
        mSpinner = new Spinner(this, null, R.style.spinner_style);
    String[] data = {"Список 0", "Список 1", "Список 2", "Список 3", "Список 4"};
    SpinnerListAdapter adapter = new SpinnerListAdapter(this, data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mToolbar.addView(mSpinner);
```

А вот его стиль:

```
<style name="spinner_style">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">7dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">7dp</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-6.0dip</item>
</style>
```

В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: может добавить еще в атрибуты <item name="android:clickable">true</item> (чисто предположение)

Comment: Добавил, нечего не поменялось.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал для начала отнаследоваться от андроидовского стиля в вашем и посмотрел, что получится. А потом бы уже добавлял свои свойства. Типа такого:

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Да я уже пробовал и от адроида, и от темы, не раскрывается. Причем если указать те стили через компоновку, в атрибуте style то они работают, spinner раскрывается...